# PHP Firestore connection fails: Google ApiCore Serializer not found in cloud-core

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm unable to connect to firestore after following the install guide, what am I missing to get this working?:

**Guide:**

- https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#linux
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#php

**Code:**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

$firestore = new FirestoreClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '/var/www/path/to/my/key.json',
    'projectId' => 'test-app',

]);
```

**Composer json:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "grpc/grpc": "^1.38",
        "google/cloud-firestore": "^0.1.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.12.1",
        "google/cloud-core": "^1.47"
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> ==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
> [Tue Oct 04 02:47:33.613513 2022] [php7:error] [pid 2826323] [client my.IP.address] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\ApiCore\Serializer' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php:93\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/google/cloud-firestore/Connection/Grpc.php(81): Google\Cloud\Core\GrpcRequestWrapper->__construct()\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/google/cloud-firestore/FirestoreClient.php(111): Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc->__construct()\n#2 /var/www/html/v.php(8): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->__construct()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php on line 93

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: @lyhong it was already being imported by another package, so the package was duplicated, causing this error

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a composer issue. I needed to remove   `"google/cloud-firestore": "^0.1.0",` and just keep  `"google/cloud-core": "^1.47"`

Updated the file and then ran: `composer require google/cloud -W`

**Composer json:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "grpc/grpc": "^1.38",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.12.1",
        "google/cloud-core": "^1.47"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR `composer require "google/cloud-firestore" "^1.37.0"`

For some reason when you require "google/cloud-firestore" composer instals very
old "^0.1.0" version by default.

That "^0.1.0" version in turn depends on "google/gax": "^0.25" that has `Google\GAX` namespace for classes like `Serializer`. The core of the error is here.

You should exec command: `composer require "google/cloud-firestore" "^1.37.0"` to install proper "google/gax": "^1.19.1" that has `Google\ApiCore\Serializer` class.