PHP webhook and google initializer
i'm trying to set  up a webhook to connect my stripe account to my firebase/firestore account and it's not working, i'm getting this message:
webhook.php - Uncaught Error: Class "Google\ApiCore\Serializer" not found in C:\Users\charl\Dropbox\Website backup\Empty-Legs-App\backend\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\GrpcRequestWrapper.php:93.
This is my PHP webhook file (beginning only):
 <?php
    // webhook.php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

    use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
    use Stripe\StripeClient;
    use Stripe\Webhook;

    try {
    $firestore = new FirestoreClient([
        'projectId' => 'corpjet2',
        'keyFilePath' => 'service-account-file.json'
    ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error initializing FirestoreClient: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
    }

i've tried everything:

deleting the vendor folder
updating
removing cache
updating dependencies
npm install @grpc/grpc-js


maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73942735/php-firestore-connection-fails-google-apicore-serializer-not-found-in-cloud-cor

i know this question, i've studied it but it didn't help. Thanks anyways.
